# How do I sort a user-defined doubly linked list in Java?

Tags: java, sorting, doubly-linked-list

I've written an insertBefore, insertAfter, insertAtHead, and insertAtTail functions, all of which I plan on incorporating into one insert() function, that will perform an insertion sort as new values are read in from a text file.

Main file:

```
/*This program utilizes linked lists to keep track of all words in a text document. It produces a cross-reference, or a concordance.
It keeps track each of the words in a given file, the number of times it occurs, and which line numbers contain the word.*/

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
public class Main
{
public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    //declare/initialize linkedlist, scanner, input string and file
    LinkedList list = new LinkedList();
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String line;
    String[] lineWords;
    File file;
    int c = 0;
    boolean done = false;
    boolean ignore;

    do
    {
        //ask for file name
        System.out.println("Please enter the filename: ");
        line = scan.next();
        file = new File(line);

        //check if file exists
        if (!file.exists())
        {
            System.out.println("That file doesn't exist. Please try again.");
            continue;
        }

        //read from file
        scan = new Scanner(file);

        //loop to display lines from file
        while (scan.hasNextLine())
        {
            line = scan.nextLine();
            c += 1;
            System.out.println(c + " " + line);

            //remove any unnecessary characters
            line = helper.format(line);

            //split line into array of words
            lineWords = line.split(" "); 

            //insert words into linkedlist 
            for (int i = 0; i < lineWords.length; i++)
            {
                //check if word should be ignored
                ignore = helper.shouldIgnore(lineWords[i]);

                //check if the current string is a word that should be ignored
                if (ignore) continue;

                //check if line contains characters
                else if (line.matches(".*\\w.*")) list.insert(lineWords[i], c);

                //otherwise don't add to the list
                else continue;
            }
        }

        //close scanner and exit do-while loop
        scan.close();
        done = true;

    } while (!done);

    //print blank line
    System.out.println("");

    //display list
    list.display();
} 
}
```

Helper file (just formatting strings and excluding words)

```
/*This file contains numerous helper functions for functionality*/

public class helper 
{
    //remove unnecessary characters
    static public String format(String s)
    {
        s = s.replace(",", "");
        s = s.replace(".", "");
        s = s.replace(";", "");
        s = s.replace(":", "");
        s = s.replace("\"", "");
        s = s.replace("?", "");
        s = s.replace("(", "");
        s = s.replace(")", "");
        s = s.replace("!", "");
        s = s.replace("\r\n", "").replace("\n", "");
        s = s.toLowerCase();
        return s;
    }

    //function to ignore a, an, and the
    static public boolean shouldIgnore(String s)
    {
        if (s.equals("the") || s.equals("The") || s.equals("a") || s.equals("A") || s.equals("an") || s.equals("An")) return true;
        else return false;
    }
}
```

And the culprit, my LinkedList file:

```
/*This file contains the functions and defining classes for linkedlists and nodes.*/

public class LinkedList
{
    //declare LinkedList values
    int size;
    Node head;
    Node tail;

    private static class Node
    {
        //node data
        String word;
        int line;
        Node next;
        Node prev;

        //constructor
        public Node(String w, int l)
        {
            this.word = w;
            this.line = l;
            this.next = null;
        }
    }

    //inserts node at head of list
    public void insert(String s, int l)
    {
        //create node to traverse through list
        Node current = head;

        //assign arguments to new node
        Node n = new Node(s, l);

        //check if list is empty
        if (head == null)
        {
            this.insertAtHead(n);
        }

        while (current != null)
        {
            if (current.word.compareTo(n.word) > 0)
            {
                System.out.println("YOOOO");
                this.insertBefore(current, n);
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("noooo");
                System.out.println(current.word + " --> " + n.word);
                this.display();
                this.insertAfter(current, n);
            } 

            current = current.next;
        }
    }

    //insert a node before a specified node
    public void insertBefore(Node a, Node n)
    {
        //make the previous of the new node the previous of the specified node
        n.prev = a.prev;

        //make the previous of the specified node the new node
        a.prev = n;

        //make the next of the new node the specified node
        n.next = a;

        //if the new node has a previous node, make the next of the previous node the new node
        if(n.prev != null) n.prev.next = n;
    }

    //insert a node after a specified node
    public void insertAfter(Node a, Node n)
    {
        //check if the previous node is null
        if (a == null) 
        { 
            System.out.println("Error. You can't insert after a null node."); 
            return; 
        }  
    
        //make next of new node the next of previous node
        n.next = a.next; 
    
        //make next of previous node the new node
        a.next = n; 
    
        //make the previous of the new node the previous node
        n.prev = a; 
    
        //make the previous of the new node's next node the new node
        if (n.next != null) n.next.prev = n; 
    }

    //insert node at head of list
    public void insertAtHead(Node n)
    {
        //Assign the head to be the node after the new node
        n.next = head; 

        //make the previous value of the new node null
        n.prev = null; 
    
        //make the previous node of the head the new node
        if (head != null) head.prev = n; 
    
        //make the head point to the new node
        head = n; 
    }

    //insert node at tail of list
    public void insertAtTail(Node n)
    {
        //make a node to use to iterate through the list
        Node last = head;
    
        //the next of the tail must be null
        n.next = null; 
    
        //check if the list is empty
        if (head == null) 
        { 
            n.prev = null; 
            head = n; 
            return; 
        } 
    
        //else iterate through the list
        while (last.next != null) last = last.next; 
    
        //make the next node of the current tail the
        last.next = n; 
    
        /* 7. Make last node as previous of new node */
        n.prev = last; 
    }

    //displays list
    public void display() {  
        //start at head
        Node n = head;

        //check if list is empty
        if(head == null) 
        {
            System.out.println("List is empty");  
            return;
        }
 
        //traverse through list
        while(n != null) 
        {  
            System.out.println(n.word);  
            n = n.next;  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Comment: I'm quite certain the issue lies in my insert() function in the LinkedList file.

Comment: What issue?

Are you able to show us the error in your console etc?

Comment: `insert()` should 1) **search** for the place where the new word belongs; 2) **insert** it there; and 3) **STOP**.  That's nothing like what it seems to be doing now.

Comment: Dylan, there's no errors in the console, but it's more an issue of an infinite while loop :(

Comment: You're right Kevin. I'm trying to use the compareTo() function to sort the nodes based on the string they contain. I just don't think I'm doing this right at all.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code with the debugger?

Comment: Yep! It seems like the problem lies in the else part of the while statement, but beyond that I am lost and confused

Comment: Like I said: **search** first, **insert** once, DONE.  What you're trying to do is: look at an existing node, add new node before or after, look at next node, add new node before or after, look at next node, insert new node before or after...

Comment: gotcha, I figured it out!